# The controller for URI is not callable symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

i get this error 
[enter image description here][1]
i have in my project 2 bundles the first one is working just fine the seconde is called DemandeBundle i get the error

```
namespace DemandeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @route("/homedemande",name="homedemande")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('@DemandeBundle/Default/index.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @route("/demande_create",name="demande_create")
 */
public function demande_create()
{
    return $this->render('@DemandeBundle/Default/demande_create.html.twig');
}
}
```

i suspect i have a problem in routing.yml

```
demande_create:
path:     /demande_create
defaults: { _controller: DemandeBundle:Default:demande_create}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your action needs to be suffixed with `Action` keyword to be callable that is probably the first issue here

function definition should be something like

```
public function demande_createAction()
```

Comment: which means  i can delete the "function indexAction" and conserve only the "function demande_createAction" ?

Comment: if you're not going to use `/homedemande` anyway, there's no need to keep it in the code. in that case you can safely remove indexAction.